# Sentry change normalizeDepth after initialization?

Tags: configuration, scope, initialization, sentry

I know I can *set* `normalizeDepth` on [initialization of Sentry](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/configuration/options/#normalize-depth) via the `init` call. But can this be ***modified*** afterwards either

1. directly on the `Sentry` instance or...
2. specific to a scope

And without affecting any other initialized values?