# Sentry pass other initialize options using AWS Lambda install?

Tags: aws-lambda, configuration, initialization, sentry

When using the [AWS Lambda integration of Sentry in the automated format](https://docs.sentry.io/product/integrations/cloud-monitoring/aws-lambda/) for Node.js, there are [two configuration values](https://docs.sentry.io/product/integrations/cloud-monitoring/aws-lambda/#node) stored in the environment variables:

```
SENTRY_TRACES_SAMPLE_RATE
SENTRY_DSN
```

Those values correspond to two [basic configuration values used with the `init` command](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/node/guides/aws-lambda/configuration/options/) to invoke Sentry:

```
dsn
tracesSampleRate
```

Since all this is rather "automated" with this setup, **is there any way to configure other initialization options**, that is to either

1. pass additional configuration options besides those two (such as [normalizeDepth](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/node/guides/aws-lambda/configuration/options/#normalize-depth) or normalizeMaxBreadth), OR ...
2. set in the Sentry dashboard itself the "base" configuration options to use, either in the lambda or project, OR ...
3. [add/reset configuration options *after* the fact](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75980916/369707)?